# The mystery of the disappearing sampi

Tags: math-mode, greek

I define a command `\msampi` - to display the archaic Greek letter sampi - by including the line

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\msampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166}
```

in the preamble. (Yes, I am specifying polutonikogreek in babel.) This works fine in the office, but I've just realized that, when I compile the file at home, the letter sampi is omitted every time from the resulting pdf. (No error message - there is simply nothing in place of the sampi.) What may be the issue? How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{polutoniko}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraitalic}      {U}{zavm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mSampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{165}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\msampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166}
\begin{document}
Hi, $\msampi$! And hi to you, $\gamma$!
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure there is not a line (not an error) in the log like `Missing character: There is no ??? in font ???` if there is such a line, could you copy it to the question?

Comment: There is no such line.

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you posted a small complete document that showed the problem

Comment: If I try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\msampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166}
\begin{document}
$\msampi$
\end{document}` I get  `! LaTeX Error: Symbol font \`extraitalic' is not defined.`  How did you define that symbol font?

Comment: I'm posting a small document below.

Comment: Don't add it _below_ add it to your question.

Comment: @HAHelfgott It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Thanks. I think "Garald" can be replaced by "H A Helfgott", which is who I am (on mathoverflow and IRL). Incidentally, I just realized that the compiler is telling me: "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/zavm/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11."

Comment: In a working version it should say `LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+zavm on input line 13.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arev/uzavm.fd
File: uzavm.fd 2006/05/30 Fontinst v1.929 font definitions for U/zavm.`  so you presumably have not installed the `arev` font support

Comment: and in the log just below that it will say `Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!` as predicted above, (I just moved my uzavm.fd to confirm)

Comment: I'll go and install texlive-fonts-extra. (In fact, I'm doing so right now, but I am on a train, so it will take a while.) I do wonder - why do I have to install this extra font? Polutoniko works fine. I've just tried using the \sampi command, outside math mode, and get the error message "! LaTeX Error: Command \textsampi unavailable in encoding OT1." Is this to be expected?

Comment: Oddly enough, I never get a "Missing character" line.

Comment: (Installing texlive-fonts-extra fixed the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have `uzavm.fd` from the arev font package setup installed (typically via tlmgr or miktex update) then (a) latex substitutes the default family and then (b) warns (in the log, not to the terminal) that that font has no character in that position:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+zavm on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file Uzavm.fd. on input line 11.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/zavm/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.

Missing character: There is no ¦ in font cmr10!
```

If the fd file (and associated fonts) are there then the log will show:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+zavm on input line 11.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arev/uzavm.fd
File: uzavm.fd 2006/05/30 Fontinst v1.929 font definitions for U/zavm.
```

the files could be installed in texlive using

```
tlmgr install arev
```

if they are not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{polutoniko}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraitalic}      {U}{zavm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mSampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{165}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\msampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166}
\begin{document}
Hi, $\msampi$! And hi to you, $\gamma$!
\end{document}
```